# Given a graphics is there a way using google to get the R package?

Tags: r

My problem is that I have a picture or graphic that I want to produce with R or to be more general with some library. Is there a way that can be applied to get the name of the R package by using the graphic as an input? The problem is that especially for beginners the names of the plots are not known, so i don#t know the name of that one for example.

For example I have this graphic I like to make in R

[image]

Which is in my case the poppr package. It is a minimum spanning tree in the
[poppr package](http://grunwaldlab.cgrb.oregonstate.edu/poppr_manual.html)

I used google reverse photo search, but the search results are showing articles about graphic design. Other search engines didn't make better job.

The code to generate this plot is following:

```
 library("poppr")
 data(Aeut)
 A.dist <- diss.dist(Aeut)
 set.seed(9005)
 poppr.msn(Aeut, A.dist, vertex.label = NA, palette = rainbow, gadj = 15)
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Looks like something you could do in `ggally` -- would be helpful to have subset of data to demonstrate.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, while interesting, it's asking about how to search, not how to solve a particular problem ...